# What happens to External List created using BCS from SQL query once the server goes offline?

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list, sql

If the database gets deleted or somehow goes offline, will the list keep the existing data or will it all be gone due to failed synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somehow database goes offline, or gets deleted, you will not access external list anymore. Because data does not reside in SharePoint and it is not SharePoint’s responsibility on how the data behaves. SharePoint is here to just present the external data.

Checkout some limitations of the External List:

- http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2010/07/bcs-external-list-limitations/
- http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/bcs-limitations/